# How can I draw basic lewis structures with chemfig, and is there any recommended documentation to follow?

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

How would I reproduce something like this in `chemfig`, and is there any documentation I should follow?

[image]

I understand this question has been asked multiple times, but I haven't found any post that goes over the basics. All of them have quite complex diagrams

Comment: [Chemfig manual](https://ftp.kddilabs.jp/CTAN/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf)

Comment: To add: ch. 1.1 "Lewis decoration", ch. 8.3 "Lewis formula". See also: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Chemical_Graphics#Lewis_Structures

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\setcharge{extra sep=0.3em}
\chemfig{\charge{85=\:,-85=\:,180=\:}{I}-\charge{90=\:}{N}(-[:-90]\charge{-90=\:,5=\:,175=\:}{I})-\charge{95=\:,0=\:,-95=\:}{I}}

\end{document}
```

[image]